# How to automatically hide/unhide rows based on cell value VBA

Tags: vba, excel, show-hide

I have a worksheet with multiple pull-down lists in Col A. The pull downs change values of the cells below in Column A to either "Skip" or some other value. I am looking to hide the rows with "Skip" in Column A, as well as the one row below the cells with value "Skip". I've got this to work on another sheet with columns of horizontally oriented data, but have gotten stuck with the data oriented vertically (in one column). I've been able to get the rows to hide, but they will not unhide when the cell value is no longer "Skip".

Here's the code I've got running currently:

```
`Sub Worksheet_Change_Hiding()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim s As String
    s = "Skip"

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    For i = 1 To 50
        Set rng = Cells(i, 1)
        If rng.EntireRow.Hidden = 0 Then
            If rng.Value = s Then rng.EntireRow.Hidden = 1
        Else
            If rng.Value <> s Then rng.EntireRow.Hidden = 0
        End If
    Next i
End Sub`
```

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyjxN.jpg)

Comment: Your code works fine, but it hides/unhides only the "Skip" row. If your problem is with the *next* row then show how you are trying to hide/unhide it.

Comment: It's not unhiding for me, is it for you?

Comment: I've been trying to solve the hide/unhide but figured it was worth noting in the off chance that hiding the additional row could be hidden/unhidden by making a small adjustment to the "Skip" hide/unhide code.  I've read about using target.value or a As Range variable i + 1 to hide the next row.

Comment: When the cell's row is hidden (because value was "Skip"), hoe does its value change so that you want to unhide it? from code?

Comment: I apologize, I am doing a terrible job explaining this.  The worksheet is a list of questions that the user answers.  Depending on the answers to the first questions (there are two and they are not hidden), some of the later (further down the sheet) questions may be instead replaced with "Skip".  This is determined by a formula in the later question or "Skip" cell.  If the answer to the earlier questions is changed, the later question or "Skip" cell may change value from "Skip" to a question or vice versa.

Comment: Thanks @A.S.H. I ended up transposing my data into row 1 and 2 to use code I already had working. Here's what I'm running now and it's working.
`Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim s As String
    s = "Skip"
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    For i = 1 To 50
        Set rng = Cells(1, i)
        If rng.EntireColumn.Hidden = 0 Then
            If rng.Value = s Then rng.EntireColumn.Hidden = 1
        Else
            If rng.Value <> s Then rng.EntireColumn.Hidden = 0
        End If
    Next i
End Sub`
Thanks again for your time, I appreciate it.